# Zoom/Pan an SVG element centered around pointer

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have written a bit of code to implement zoom and pan to an SVG element on a HTML page.

I am trying to extend this, so that the zoom effect is centered around the mouse cursor, and this is what I am struggling with.

**Edit:** By centered around the mouse cursor, I mean the point at the cursor should remain at the cursor after the zoom in/out.

It seems to me that I have to pan the element a bit, relative to the mouse cursors position and the relation between the existing zoom value and the new zoom value, but I can not figure out how to do this.

Could someone help me with the math?

I have fiddled with the math for quite some time now, and have come up with a number of failed computations, for the values that I need to add to the XY pan. I've also found a lot of zoom/pan code on i.e. github, but nothing that I could incorporate into my own code. Most of it uses one or more libraries, and I would much prefer to implement this in a bit of code rather than a bunch of libraries.

For reference, here is my code. I was unsure how much to post, and in which format, so here is the html, css and js, all in one block.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ZoomPanView</title>
    <style>
        svg {
            background-color: silver;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        const MOUSE_EVENT_PRIMARY_PHASE = 2;

        let viewBoxX = 0;
        let viewBoxY = 0;
        let viewBoxZ = 400;
        let viewBoxMinZ = 400;
        let viewBoxMaxZ = 1200;
        const VIEWBOX_INCREMENTS = viewBoxZ / 10;

        let isDragging = false;
        let dragOffsetX, dragOffsetY;

        function mouseDown()
        {
            // Validate that the current target is the view/svg element.
            if(event.eventPhase != MOUSE_EVENT_PRIMARY_PHASE)
                return;
            if(event.currentTarget.id != "view")
                return;

            // Store the current state.
            isDragging = true;
            dragOffsetX = event.clientX;
            dragOffsetY = event.clientY;
        }

        function mouseUp()
        {
            isDragging = false;
        }

        function mouseMove()
        {
            if(isDragging)
            {
                let deltaX = event.clientX - dragOffsetX;
                let deltaY = event.clientY - dragOffsetY;

                viewBoxX += deltaX;
                viewBoxY += deltaY;

                dragOffsetX = event.clientX;
                dragOffsetY = event.clientY;

                var view = document.getElementById('view');
                view.setAttribute("viewBox", -viewBoxX + " " + -viewBoxY + " " + viewBoxZ + " " + viewBoxZ);
            }
        }

        function mouseWheel()
        {
            if(event.deltaY < 0)
            {
                viewBoxZ -= VIEWBOX_INCREMENTS;
                if(viewBoxZ < viewBoxMinZ)
                {
                    viewBoxZ = viewBoxMinZ;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if(event.deltaY > 0)
            {
                viewBoxZ += VIEWBOX_INCREMENTS;
                if(viewBoxZ > viewBoxMaxZ)
                {
                    viewBoxZ = viewBoxMaxZ;
                    return;
                }
            }

            /* Get the mouse pointer coordinates relative to the view/svg object.
            rect = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
            viewX = (event.clientX - rect.left) * (viewBoxZ / viewBoxMinZ);
            viewY = (event.clientY - rect.top) * (viewBoxZ / viewBoxMinZ);
            */

            var view = document.getElementById('view');
            view.setAttribute("viewBox", -viewBoxX + " " + -viewBoxY + " " + viewBoxZ + " " + viewBoxZ);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <svg id="view" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()" onmousemove="mouseMove()" onmousewheel="mouseWheel()">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="yellow">
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021913/svg-pan-zoom-pan-zoom-to-any-object?rq=1 of interest

Comment: As far as I can tell (and I may be wrong here) the way they implement a mouse pointer focused zoom in https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom, is by translating by the pointer coordinates, performing the zoom and then translating by the negative pointer coordinates, which seems elegant, but how would I do that when using a viewBox instead of a transformation matrix?

Comment: Oh you mean the panToElem function, right?

Comment: to be honest I have not studied their code ( on github ) bt just noticed the method `enableMouseWheelZoom` in the answer and thought it might be relevant

Comment: I've had a bit more time to read it now. The library in the post uses matrix transforms and the solution in the stackoverflow post centers the view on a given point. It's close, but not quite what I'm after. Thanks for the link anyway though.

Comment: "how would I do that when using a viewBox instead of a transformation matrix?" You translate the viewBox to the origin, scale it, then translaste it back.